MongoDB getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal
I tried to create a replica set with on my docker-compose file, the replica set members are up and running and i also can connect with mongosh -- and i can run rs.status().
But i cannot connect the mongoDB Compass with the connection string below.
When i tried to connect compass i got this error:
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal
Here's my App Module which includes the connection string
      'mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/?replicaSet=rs0&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000',
      {
        maxStalenessSeconds: 120,
        readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred',
      },
    )

Here's my docker-compose file:
services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:7.0
    command: ['--replSet', 'rs0', '--bind_ip_all', '--port', '27017']
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    healthcheck:
      test: echo "try { rs.status() } catch (err) { rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:27017',priority:1},{_id:1,host:'localhost:27018',priority:0.5},{_id:2,host:'localhost:27019',priority:0.5}]}) }" | mongosh --port 27017 --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      start_period: 0s
      start_interval: 1s
      retries: 30
    volumes:
      - 'mongo1_data:/data/db'
      - 'mongo1_config:/data/configdb'

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:7.0
    command: ['--replSet', 'rs0', '--bind_ip_all', '--port', '27018']
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    volumes:
      - 'mongo2_data:/data/db'
      - 'mongo2_config:/data/configdb'

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:7.0
    command: ['--replSet', 'rs0', '--bind_ip_all', '--port', '27019']
    ports:
      - 27019:27019
    volumes:
      - 'mongo3_data:/data/db'
      - 'mongo3_config:/data/configdb'

volumes:
  mongo1_data:
  mongo2_data:
  mongo3_data:
  mongo1_config:
  mongo2_config:
  mongo3_config:


I am not seeing where host.docker.internal comes into it.

There s no log for it. On compass its just said that.
